# How to draw a line based on a point and a slope? (SD line)

Tags: r

To examine the association between two variables, I'd like to draw the SD line, which is defined as

> "the line that goes through the point of averages and climbs at the
>   rate of one vertical SD for each horizontal SD" *Freedman, D., Pisani, R., & Purves, R. (2007). Statistics (4th edn).*

Therefore, it's a basic question of analytic geometry: Draw a line given a point and a slope. Attempting to do this, `abline()` seems like the most relevant tool. However, `abline()` requires the intercept, though my given point isn't necessarily on the y-axis.

### Example: Examining the association between *weight* and *mpg* in `mtcars`

```r
data(mtcars)

## calculate means
mean_wt <- mean(mtcars$wt)
mean_mpg <- mean(mtcars$mpg)

## calculate standard deviations
sd_wt <- sd(mtcars$wt)
sd_mpg <- sd(mtcars$mpg)

## scatter plot
plot(x = mtcars$wt, y = mtcars$mpg)

## add the "point of averages"
points(mean_wt, mean_mpg, col = "red", cex = 1.5, pch = 16)
```

[image: plot]

### Now, I want to draw the SD line as follows

[image: sdline]

### calculate the line slope as the ratio of SDs:

```r
slope <- -1*sd_mpg/sd_wt
## [1] -6.159643
```

**My question:** given `slope` and a point `(mean_wt, mean_mpg)`, how can I draw the line as in the illustration?

Comment: Hi Emman, for the example, you flipped the points argument, it should be points(mean_wt, mean_mpg, col = "red", cex = 1.5, pch = 16)

Comment: I now corrected it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a line using "curve" as below. Remember to include "add = TRUE"

```
data(mtcars)

## calculate means
mean_wt <- mean(mtcars$wt)
mean_mpg <- mean(mtcars$mpg)

## calculate standard deviations
sd_wt <- sd(mtcars$wt)
sd_mpg <- sd(mtcars$mpg)

## scatter plot
plot(x = mtcars$wt, y = mtcars$mpg)

## add the "point of averages"
points(mean_wt, mean_mpg, col = "red", cex = 1.5, pch = 19)

slope <- -1*sd_mpg/sd_wt

curve(expr = x*slope + (mean_mpg - slope*mean_wt), add = TRUE, col = 'blue')
```

which produces the following figure:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can calculate the interception point. Here is the function.

```
get_intercept <- function(x1, y1, slope) {
    # Point slope formula (y - y1) = slope(x - x1)
    y_intercept = slope * (- x1) + y1
    return(y_intercept)
}
```

For your example:

```
get_intercept(mean_wt, mean_mpg, slope)
```

Gives:

```
[1] 39.90773
```

Now you can use `abline`:

```
abline(39.90773, slope)
```

Comment: Sorry my stupidity, but where did you get this formula of the intercept? Is the same as y = mx + b?